# Why can we treat probability density function the same way as probability itself when doing calculations

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I noticed that the density function also has formula that are direct analogs of discrete probability in the sense that we can apply the law of total probability or Bayes' Rule to the density function itself, for example:

$f(x|y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f(y)}$ is the analog of $P(x|y) = \frac{P(x,y)}{P(y)}$

or how we "integrate out" a variable in f(x,y) to get marginal distribution the same way we would "sum out" a variable in P(x,y) to get marginal probabilities.

In discrete case, with the definition of probability, these formula and operations make sense to me, but can someone please explain both intuitively and mathematically how the same formula exist for PDF as well?

Thank you.